# Show childs after their parents in a self referenced table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a self-referenced table like this one

```
------------------------------
| ID | Name       | ParentID |
| 1  | Fruits     |          |
| 2  | Vegetables |          |
| 3  | Animals    |          |
| 4  | Whatever   |          |
| 6  | Orange     | 1        |
| 7  | Apple      | 1        |
| 8  | Banana     | 1        |
------------------------------
```

I need to do a query in order to retrieve the data as follows:

```
------------------------------
| ID | Name       | ParentID |
| 1  | Fruits     |          |
| 6  | Orange     | 1        |
| 7  | Apple      | 1        |
| 8  | Banana     | 1        |
| 2  | Vegetables |          |
| 3  | Animals    |          |
| 4  | Whatever   |          |
------------------------------
```

Showing the parent before the childs whenever it applies.

Comment: What database vendor are you using?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3d6/1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using some variant of SQL Server, you need to use a common table expression with some kind of path/breadcrumb column included...

```
;with cte as 
(
   select Id, Name, ParentID,
          convert(nvarchar(max), [Id]) as Breadcrumb
     from dbo.Location
    where ParentID is null
   --
   union all
   --
   select l.Id, l.Name, l.ParentID,
          cte.BreadCrumb + '\' + convert(nvarchar(max), l.[Id]) as Breadcrumb
     from dbo.Location l
    inner join cte on l.ParentId = cte.Id
)

select * 
  from cte
 order by Breadcrumb
```

**Edit:** You can use ID or Name as your breadcrumb value - depends how you want to sort your data really.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL server:

```
select * from MyTable
order by
case when ID in (select distinct parentID from MyTable) 
     then ID - 0.5 else isnull(parentID, 100000) end
, ID
```

Checks to see if an ID is a parent - if so, sorts it to just above the records that have it as a parent (by subtracting 0.5 from the ID).

Note: the `isnull(parentID, 100000)` is just an arbitrary large value to drop rows that neither are a parent nor have a parent to the bottom of the list - adjust as needed based on your data.  You may want to replace 100,000 with a calculated value based on the largest ID in your table, if you have a lot of data and/or it changes frequently.

Comment: I like this. Question though - will the `select distinct` be run for each row?

Comment: `select distinct` is probably unnecessary in this case, but I like to include it for troubleshooting purposes (mostly a habit at this point).  I'm not sure if performance will make a difference here - it's unclear from the question how much data is being worked with.  OP may want to try with a join instead of a subquery if there is a lot of data.

Comment: Think I might have just spotted a flaw - I don't think it will work if the ID of the parent record is higher than that of the child. It's a real shame if that's the case as I thought it was a really elegant solution (and I'd rather write this than a CTE any day)

Comment: @amcdermott - when I tested with fruit = ID 12, it did still work.  If the fruit ID is 12, it assigns a sort order of 11.5, and the children a sort order of 12 (followed by the order of their own IDs).

Comment: This is why I used the case statement, instead of the `coalesce`/`isnull` other posters had suggested.

Comment: That's odd - doesn't work with data I had mocked up.

Comment: Actually - are you using MySQL.The #temp doesn't compile in SQL Server for me - but if I change to `MyTable` it works... except when the ID of the parent is greater than the ID of the child.

Comment: @amcdermott thanks!  I am using sql-server, but created a temp table for testing purposes and forgot to change the second reference to MyTable.  I have corrected it.